# router doesnt redirect at first attempt

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue application that is connected to Firebase and is using Vue router. I have a Login page and UserProfile page, when user enters their credentials, I want to redirect them to the UserPage using router, like this:

```
submit() {
 firebase
 .auth()
 .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.email, this.form.password)
 .then(data => {
   console.log("data", data);
   this.$router.push({ name: "profile" }).catch(err => {
     console.log("err");
   });
 })
 .catch(err => {
   this.error = err.message;
 });
}
```

The weird thing is, that when I try to login, first attempt displays 'data' in the console and then the 'err" (which is undefined) and it doesnt redirect, but still logs in to user account. When I click submit button again, then it shows 'data' again but no 'err' and redirects to the UserProfile page. I cant figure out why its happening, any help would be appreciated!

The form and button code:

```
<form action="#" @submit.prevent="submit">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control"
                name="email" value required autofocus v-model="form.email"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control"
                name="password" required v-model="form.password"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

plus submit method:

```
methods: {
 submit() {
   firebase
     .auth()
     .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.email, this.form.password)
     .then(data => {
       console.log("data", data);
       this.$router.push({ name: "profile" }).catch(err => {
         console.log("err", err);
       });
     })
     .catch(err => {
       this.error = err.message;
     });
  }
}
```

Router config (index.js):

```
Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
mode: "history",
base: process.env.BASE_URL,
routes: [
  {
    path: "*",
    redirect: "/games"
  },
  {
    path: "/games",
    name: "games",
    component: Games
  },
  {
  path: "/games/:game",
  name: "game",
  component: Game
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    name: "profile",
    component: Profile,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    component: Register
  }
]
});
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
  // this route requires auth, check if logged in
  // if not, redirect to login page.
  if (!store.getters.user.loggedIn) {
  next({ name: "login" });
  } else {
    next(); // go to wherever I'm going
  }
} else {
 next(); // does not require auth, make sure to always call next()!
}
});
export default router;
```

Comment: Can you share your form and button code (part in the `template`) as well as your router config (`index.js` file)?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some side effects due to the `action` value. You actually don't need to submit your form, just to call the Firebase `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method.

I would change your code as follows:

**template:**

```
 <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control"
            name="email" value required autofocus v-model="form.email"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control"
            name="password" required v-model="form.password"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
          <button type="button" @click="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

**script:**

```
methods: {
 login() {
   firebase
     .auth()
     .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.email, this.form.password)
     .then(data => {
       console.log("data", data);
       this.$router.push({ name: "profile" })
       });
     })
     .catch(err => {
       this.error = err.message;
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: still the same problem :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can help you anymore. IMO this should work.